# Downloading File in Parallelwith Asyncio

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I trying to pull Avro files from an API link while using Asyncio. Currently it just returns nothing if the link is to an avro file - while all my other API calls which pull json data work. What am I missing?

```
credentials = {'authorization': XXXXX}

async def get_data(link, session,creds)-> None:
        async with session.get(url, url=link, headers=credential) as res:
            content = await res.read()
        r = await session.request('GET', url=str(link), headers=creds)
        data = await r
        return
async def data_distributor_function(credential)-> None:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        link_list = ["https://.....","https://.....","https://.....","https://.....","https://....."]
        tasks = []
        for link in link_list:
            tasks.append(wait_for(get_data( link=link, session=session,creds=credential),timeout=10))
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    return

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
data = asyncio.run(data_distributor_function(credential),debug=True)
```

If I don't do the API call in asyncio, I can just use a standard request and it works (it's just slow).
`reply = requests.request("GET", link, credentials)`

Comment: Could it be that your timeout is reached? Since you mentioned that it is slow with standard request

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't the casue. I'm download around 6 files, each take about 1 second, and I've experimented with stretching the timeout to 100 seconds.

Comment: What happens if you rename avro file from my_avro_file.avsc to my_avro_file.json?

Comment: have you tried parallelizing requests.request, session.get is expecting a http response